# Picker Views and if statements

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipickerview

I have created a successful pickerview using this tutorial:

[Link to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHkEUibsShM)

I want to be able to do something different when each option is selected whereas most tutorials just show how to do one thing for all options e.g. putting the option text into a label.

This is the code I have attempting to do what I want. (I put in the print part to see if the code was being run and it wasn't.)

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0 {
            currentSpeedMeasurement = "MPH"
            speed = speed * 2.23694
            print("Testing")
        }else if row == 1 {
            currentSpeedMeasurement = "KPH"
            speed = speed * 3.6
        } else if row == 2 {
            currentSpeedMeasurement = "M/S"
            speed = locationManager.location!.speed
            //speed = round(100 * speed)
        }
    }
```

Edit: Below is all of my code for the project. I am creating an app that shows the speed the person is travelling at. 
I want the user to pick a speed measurement from the PickerView (named measurementPicker) e.g. MPH.

I want the switch to activate depending on what option the user selects using the switch statement.

I want the speed to then be displayed in a label (having been converted to the desired measurement) with the measurement afterwards. E.G. "Your speed: 10 MPH"

The switch doesn't seem to be running because the measurement is always m/s.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: is it coming to didSelectRow method of pickerview..?

Comment: Try to print(pickerView) and print(component) in the beginning of a method. And print("Testing") in the rest of situation (when row is 1 and when 2)and make also } else { condition, that catches all the rest .

Comment: Have you added UIPickerViewDelegate like 'class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {} ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That may be the  problem. I have added UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource but haven't added the UIPickerViewControllerDelegate you mentioned. I have tried to add it but it doesn't come up as that. Is it actually named "UIDocumentPickerViewController"?

Comment: I have updated the original post. Please read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good, i think it will be better using switch

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    switch row {
    case 0:
        currentSpeedMeasurement = "MPH"
        speed = speed * 2.23694
        print("Testing")
    case 1:
        currentSpeedMeasurement = "KPH"
        speed = speed * 3.6
    default:
        currentSpeedMeasurement = "M/S"
        speed = locationManager.location!.speed
        //speed = round(100 * speed)
    }
}
```

why it's not working? i think you're missing setting delegate for the picker, do it through your storyboard

[image: Setting delegate via storyboard]

or via code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView! {
        didSet{
            pickerView.delegate = self
            pickerView.dataSource = self
        }
    }
```

and it should work fine with you after.

Comment: Please make sure that the delegation work, add simple print inside the function and see if it prints

Comment: Also switch is depending on the row, not the value of the row so it would definitely be better than if statements

Comment: I have added the prints and nothing is being printed so I assume the code is not being called upon.

Comment: Have you added the delegation as i explained?

Comment: I think it was already added.  This is the code I have showing this: class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

Comment: Now you have the protocols added, you've to add the delegation as i explained above, do it and let me know the results

Comment: The data source delegation was missing but still the same results

Comment: still doesn't do the simple print? can you add the full class code?

Comment: I have added it. Its added to the original post. Added about 10mins ago

Comment: I think the problem may be something to do with the function only being made and not called/ used. I don't know how to call it.

Comment: I think using selectedRowInComponent may help

Comment: That's where the delegate part work, you need to understand it

Comment: also i can't see the full code above, make sure you added it

Comment: okay, now it's spotted, you can't use that function inside the function as you're doing, it has to be outside like class function, fix that and it will work immediately!

Comment: So where should I move it to?

Comment: To the top, it can't be inside any function

Comment: But the speed variable is created inside the locationManager function so then it doesn't work!

Comment: that's what i meant by fixing, move the var outside that function too if you depend on it